# Bubble sort String array and int array

Tags: java, arrays

Here I want to make a bubble sort that compares all the names of type string
in the array names in alphabetic order; like B and A ---> A and B.
And when I do this change I also want to change the position of the `itemsToSell` array so all the right names have the right numbers next to them. I can't use `java.util.Arrays`; Any advice?

```java
public static void printNames(String[] name, int[] itemsToSell, int[] amountBought) {
    boolean flag = true;

    while (flag) {
        flag = false;

        for (int j = 0; j < name.length - 1; j++) {
            for (int i = j + 1; i < name.length; i++) {
                if (name[i].compareTo(name[j]) < 0) {
                    int tempTtem = itemsToSell[j];
                    itemsToSell[j] = itemsToSell[i];
                    itemsToSell[i] = tempTtem;

                    String temp = name[j];
                    name[j] = name[i];
                    name[i] = temp;

                }
            }

            System.out.println(name[j] + '\t' + itemsToSell[j] + "\t\t" + amountBought[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class Main {

    public static void bubbleSort(String[] name, int[] itemsToSell) {
        while (true) {
            boolean sorted = moveRight(name, itemsToSell);
            sorted &= moveLeft(name, itemsToSell);

            if (sorted)
                break;
        }
    }

    private static boolean moveRight(String[] name, int[] itemsToSell) {
        boolean sorted = true;

        for (int i = 0, j = 1; j < name.length; i++, j++) {
            if (name[i].compareTo(name[j]) > 0) {
                sorted = false;
                swap(itemsToSell, i, j);
                swap(name, i, j);
            }
        }

        return sorted;
    }

    private static boolean moveLeft(String[] name, int[] itemsToSell) {
        boolean sorted = true;

        for (int j = name.length - 1, i = j - 1; i >= 0; i--, j--) {
            if (name[i].compareTo(name[j]) > 0) {
                sorted = false;
                swap(itemsToSell, i, j);
                swap(name, i, j);
            }
        }

        return sorted;
    }

    private static void swap(String[] arr, int i, int j) {
        String tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = tmp;
    }

    private static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
        int tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = tmp;
    }

}
```